# Cokernel of morphism defined by a section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over the field of complex numbers. Let $V$ be a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $r$. Suppose $s\in H^0(X,V)$ then we have an injective morphism given by 
$$0\rightarrow O_X\rightarrow V\,.$$
What is the cokernel of the above morphism? If $V$ is rank two is it given by $\text{det }V$?

Comment: What about the inclusion of $\mathcal{O}_X$ in $\mathcal{O}_X(P)$, where $P$ is a point on $X$?

Comment: @Ariyan, I know that the cokernel  that case is a skyscraper sheaf supported at $P$. I am interested in the case when rank is two, which I have already mentioned in the question

Comment: For the cokernel to be a vector bundle, one need that $s$ does not vanish.